# Social Sharing Angularjs sharing image URL as a photo not a link to photo

Tags: angularjs, sharing

I'm using https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare for social sharing , i want to share the image url as Image not as a link to image.
I want to know if there is a way i can do this.

Comment: Can you precise your case? I think you cannot share a picture the same way that you can do in Facebook with images from Facebook itself. What you share a link, Facebook then attempts to get a preview of the link content, if the link targets directly an image, you should have the link and under it a preview of the image. Isn't it what you get? Facebook will of course be unable to render this image internally as if it was in facebook itself, so you need a link somewhere to access what's been shared.

Comment: It shares the link with the preview with some websites like facebook and some other providers like twitter is shares only the link without the preview so i want to share the photo itself like what you just said posting from facebook but i don't know how. I think it doesn't affect security because in  both cases the user will have to check what is being shared.

Comment: This will be much more complicated (when possible). This depends on the API of the site you want to share. For ex, it's possible in Facebook to import content in a page, but it requires the creation of a Facebook App ("FB APP ID" in the plugin docs refers to that). The whole process is more complex than just sharing a link, you need to be registered as dev, etc. For Twitter, if there's an API for that, it doesn't seem supported by your plugin. If you read the properties available per provider in the plugin docs, it seems it doesn't allow you to specify a preview image for Twitter either.